# Instagram API Python error

Tags: python, instagram-api

I'm trying to familiarize with the library [python-instagram](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram).

I've done this code:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
clientid = '***'
clientsecret = '***'
api = InstagramAPI(client_id=clientid, client_secret=clientsecret)
tag_name = raw_input("Write the word that you want")
filtered_media = api.tag_recent_media(count=20, max_id=1, tag_name=tag_name)
for media in filtered_media:
    print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

and I get the following error using the command line (I have a mac):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    filtered_media = api.tag_recent_media(count=20, max_id=1, tag_name=tag_name)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/instagram/bind.py", line 197, in _call
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/instagram/bind.py", line 189, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/instagram/bind.py", line 163, in _do_api_request
instagram.bind.InstagramAPIError: (400) OAuthAccessTokenException-The access_token provided is invalid.
```

Someone knows what is happen? THANKS

Comment: Are you sure the acces_token provided is valid? [Here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram#obtaining-an-access-token) the library talks about access tokens.

Comment: @syntonym how can I get an access_token? I've found this website (http://instagram.pixelunion.net/), but I don't think that it's the best way to get it :)

Comment: The `Here` in the above is a link to the following webpage: https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram#obtaining-an-access-token where you are walked through obtaining a access token.

Comment: @syntonym I've tried to get the acces_token, but they ask me for the "Requested scope (separated by spaces, blank for just basic read):"......what is it exactly?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/)

Comment: @syntonym
ok, I've tried to do it, but I've received the following message:

"Sorry, this page isn't available.

The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed. Go back to Instagram."

I can't do it...

Comment: python-instagram states: `This project is not actively maintained. Proceed at your own risk!` so i think you are out of luck. Maybe you can obtain an access token manually by following the directions of instagram.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at this [sample app](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/blob/master/sample_app.py) . You will get to know how to use python-instagram library.

In your code , You are passing client Id in `InstagramAPI()`. But as per their sample app required argument is access_token.

code snippet from sample_app.py

```
    api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=CONFIG['client_secret'])
    tag_search, next_tag = api.tag_search(q="backclimateaction")
    tag_recent_media, next = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name=tag_search[0].name)
```

To get tag_search result you must have `access_token`. you can read this [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) to learn how to generate access token from your app.